# how do create a commenting feature in asp.net which fetches data from database and displays it on webform along with their name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, panel, comments

[The sample has been attached for your reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqYt6.png)
I am trying to create a commenting system similar to the reference. The Users should be able to comment about particular issue and i want it to display as a stack in a panel like view along with their name and timestamp on the comment above. I have no clue how to display them as a stack with their name on top of comment apart from doing it in a gridview way. Any help is much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should at least check out all the controls for the platform that you are working on. Apart from Grid, there are many controls which you can utilize to build the page that stacks comments.

You can use check out all the data controls [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx) The choice is up to you but i would suggest that you go with Repeater as that is built for producing such repetitive blocks.

you can sort your comments data by `"id desc"` so that latest comments show up on top. The look of the blocks depends on how you style them using css.